# Trouble with Textures

Tags: opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

I'm having a bit of trouble with a texture.  I'm writing a program that processes some raw data from a binary file, does some FFTs (using JTransform), scales the data to a single signed byte, and display it.  Everything is going well except the display.

The data in memory is a 512 by 500 `byte[]` that should be rendered on a 512 by 500 texture.  Using LIBGDX, I do the following:

1. Create a subclass of `Actor`
2. Create a 512 by 500 `Texture`
3. Create a `Sprite` using the `Texture` in step 2
4. In the 'Actor' draw method, I use the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL20.GL_LUMINANCE, 500, 512, 0, GL20.GL_LUMINANCE, GL20.GL_BYTE, data);     //Data is a byte[]
   }
   ```

The problem:  The screen is only displaying a fraction of the data.  It appears that the `Texture` is really zoomed in and only displaying around 20 by 20 pixels

Things I've tried that haven't worked:

1. Changing the `Stage` camera to see if it is a camera clipping issue
2. Scaling the `Sprite` to see if it is a camera clipping issue
3. Using `glViewport` to see if it is a camera clipping issue
4. Populating the rendered byte[] with 0 and 1 to ensure that it is not a data processing issue
5. Tested it on my phone and two desktops to check it is a weird viewport issue
6. Google and StackOverflow

Nothing has worked, help!

Comment: You say the data is 512x500, but your `glTexImage2D` call specifies 500x512. Also, what's your drawing code and shaders?

Comment: @Colonel - If the 512 by 500 is backwards it just messes up the image a bit, no big deal.  As for the code, I'd be happy to post it, there are no shaders and for drawing code, the above code is all that I'm calling in the `draw` method.

Comment: Try calling `Gdx.gl.glPixelStorei(GL20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` before uploading the bytes. By default it reads the bytes aligned to words: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelStorei.xml By the way, I sense a potential bug. You aren't specifying which texture you're uploading the data to. I'm guessing that's only working because your app only has one Texture in it right now, so the texture's already bound from the previous frame.

Comment: @Tenfour04 - You are correct, it is just binding to the screen, which is fine for now.  I tried adding `glPixelStorei` as suggested, but this does not work either.

Comment: @Tenfour04 - It works now!  I added a `Texture`, drew it, bound it, and it worked!  It was all messed up because the texture it was binding to was all zoomed in.  Thank you!  The correct answer is about not having a proper texture, I'll vote it correct if you write it up.